# How to implement the fix for Forward Secrecy on Debian Apache OpenSSL?

Tags: tls, openssl, apache

My SSL test result was an A- due to forward secrecy.

I want to know how to implement the fix mentioned on this page here:
https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2013/06/25/ssl-labs-deploying-forward-secrecy

Specifically the lines:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
```

In my `apache2.conf` file I have an `SSLProtocol` line and then below that I can place the `SSLCipherSuite` line, that's where I assume these forward secrecy fix lines are supposed to go.

For example from this question here:

https://community.qualys.com/thread/11796

I see their SSLCipherSuite line as:

```
ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:AES128-GCM-SHA256:RC4:HIGH:!MD5:!aNULL
```

Looking at the Apache SSL doc I see the pattern above.

I just don't know how to put three lines, are they separated by commmas, or use three separate lines, or do those lines go somewhere else?

Comment: They will all come on a single line separated by a colon. Use https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/ for generating the SSL conf for your server.

Comment: @void_in Thanks for your response. I will check out that link.

Comment: @void_in Just a quick question, am I supposed to keep the TLS_ in front of the ECDHE_RSA... for example? I tried both and my server went down. I use KATE for a text editor/IDE and the HonorCipherOrder wasn't highlighted (usually suggests invalid/not-supported) but I see it on that link that you sent. Actually I think I know what I did wrong.

Comment: still broken, probably should have mentioned that I'm using Apache 2.4.10

Comment: This is not a question about information security but about the exact syntax of a specific setting in the server configuration. Thus it would be more relevant for serverfault.com. But since such information can easily be found using a search engine or by looking at the servers documentation I recommend to close the question rather than to move it.

Comment: Check out the [Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/). It supports what seems to me to be all of the common web servers except Microsoft IIS, has a few knobs you can tweak to suit your needs, and gives you a configuration file snippet back that you can include into your configuration as-is. Very convenient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are NOT lines:

```
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
```

These are ciphers and should go inside the `SSLCipherSuite` in appropriate form.

**Implementation:**

First, make sure that there is no other `SSLCipherSuite` (except vhosts) that may override your new cipher suite settings. If there is, comment it.

Then, below the commented line or below `SSLProtocol` line paste your cipher suite. It should look for example like this:

```
SSLCipherSuite ECDHE-ECDSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:DHE-RSA-CHACHA20-POLY1305:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:!DSS
```

Explanation:

- the first is directive (SSLCipherSuite) for Apache server
- ciphers (e.g. `DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256`) or cipher groups (e.g. `DSS`) are separated by colon (`:`)
- exclamation mark after a colon means that this cipher or group should be left out
- plus after colon means that this cipher or group should go at the end

By the way, don´t use the cipher suite you mentioned in question. [RC4 is obsolete *and prohibited in TLS since over a year*.](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7465) (Thanks @Michael Kjörling)

Comment: Thanks for your post. My problem might be that I'm missing double-quotes around the cipher-suite string, I also didn't know about the !DSS part. Someone showed me their settings that got them an A+ SSL rating. I will implement your response and see what happens thanks for your time.

Comment: In Apache config, you do not use quotes around directive values. This syntax is used in Nginx.

Comment: @JacobDavidCunningham - By the way, the cipher suite I posted I am actually using and I am getting A+  -  [proof](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=sufix.cz&s=2a01%3a9420%3a41%3a100%3a0%3a0%3a0%3a1&latest)

Comment: RC4 isn't merely obsolete. [RC4 ciphersuites are **prohibited** in TLS](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7465) since over a year, and currently Qualys SSL Labs cap grades to C for hosts that talk RC4 with "modern protocols". (They cap grades to B for hosts that talk RC4 with "older protocol versions" only, but that's little comfort if the client or server can be tricked into downgrading to earlier protocols without any warning or error.) See also [RC4 in TLS is Broken: Now What?](https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2013/03/19/rc4-in-tls-is-broken-now-what) (March 2013).